# Springboot 2 Oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

I have been working with spring for quite a while. And I used the early versions of Spring boot and was amazed by it. But the teams in springboot keep changing things in every release without providing any good documentation. 
Here is the problem I am facing. I don't need solutions I just need to understand.
I have an IdentityServer acting as my SSO. I have a bunch of applications in java and .net with a rest API. I need to create a Gateway Application that will be called by web cleints ( Web, Mobile ..). This gateway will take in charge the authentication of the user on the SSO or the validation of it's token if he is already connected.
So we chose spring boot because it's "Simple" to configure. So I got the last version of Spring boot and tried. I wanted to have an Authorization Service and a Resource Service on the same Application.
The thing is I found a lot of annotations and keywords that seem to do the same thing but at the same time they are not the same.
Is there any place where we can find a documentation about Spring boot 2.0 Oauth security ? Does anyone know a book or a tutorial or a website that could shed some light upon this mystery ?
Last if you have an idea about those : @EnableOAuth2Sso VS @EnableOAuth2Client VS @EnableResourceServer VS @EnableAuthorizationServer VS @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
And at lats what is the main purpose of the different Configurer classes and should I implement a Filter to intercept the Authentification ???!
Sorry about the long  message but after two days working with Spring boot 2 and Oauth 2 I feel like I had lost all what I know about OpenId Specification !

Comment: The lack of any sort of formatting makes this difficult to read.

Comment: I am not writing a letter ^^

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [migration guide for Spring Boot 2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#oauth2), OAuth2 functionality is being migrated to core Spring Security. For anything that has not been migrated yet, you can add an [additional jar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) to take advantage of some auto-configuration. Documentation on creating an [Authorization Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-authorization-server) and [Resource Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server) can also be found there.